# Windows JNI Loading and executing c++ code in dll error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Answer/Solution: To be clear Jorn Vernee's answer is correct in that when i created my .h file originally i didnt have the package information in the .java class but when my code was executed it did have the package information.  The method names in the .h file will end up including the package information in the name.

I've got some C++ code that i use to take a screen shot.  I've been attempting to call it from Java using both JNA and JNI and having no luck with either.  My ultimate goal is to get the captureScreen method working. I created a getNumber method just as a simple test with no parameters passed in but even it wouldnt work.

**Update** My application is running as a 64 bit application and my dll is 64 bit.  Not sure if that affects the parameters passed in or out.

My current implementation

Java

```
public class JNIScreenShotTest { 
   static {
  String oldLibraryPath = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
  try{
  //This doesnt work for me it fails on the loadLibrary call and I get an UnsatisfiedLinkError
  //System.setProperty("java.library.path", "C:\\workspace\\com.tdkc.udop\dlls");
  //System.loadLibrary("JNIScreenShot"); 
                               
  //This Manages to load the library without error                         
  System.load("C:\\workspace\\com.tdkc.udop\\dlls\\JNIScreenShot.dll")
  }finally}
      System.setProperty("java.library.path", oldLibraryPath );
  }
 }

  private native void captureScreen(String filePath, int x, int y, int width, int height);

  private native int getNumber();

}
```

I used javac -h to create my header file from the above class

.h file

```
    /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
    #include <jni.h>
    /* Header for class JNIScreenShot */

    #include "DXGICapture.h"

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <shlobj.h>
    #include <atlconv.h>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    #ifndef _Included_JNIScreenShot
    #define _Included_JNIScreenShot
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif
        /*
         * Class:     JNIScreenShot
         * Method:    captureScreen
         * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;IIII)V
         */
        JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIScreenShot_captureScreen
        (JNIEnv*, jobject, jstring, jint, jint, jint, jint);

        /*
     * Class:     JNIScreenShotTest
     * Method:    getNumber
     * Signature: ()I
     */
        JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JNIScreenShotTest_getNumber
        (JNIEnv*, jobject);

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif
    #endif
```

C++ file

```
    // ScreenCapture.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL.
//


#include "JNIScreenShot.h"
#include <iostream>


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIScreenShot_captureScreen
(JNIEnv *env, jobject clz, jstring filePath, jint x, jint y, jint width, jint height) {
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CDXGICapture dxgiCapture;
    jboolean isCopy;
    const char* pszOutputFileName = (env)->GetStringUTFChars(filePath, &isCopy);

    hr = dxgiCapture.Initialize();
    tagScreenCaptureFilterConfig config;

    // set default config
    RtlZeroMemory(&config, sizeof(config));
    config.ShowCursor = 1;
    config.SizeMode = tagFrameSizeMode_AutoSize;

    hr = dxgiCapture.SetConfig(config);
    hr = dxgiCapture.CaptureToFile((LPCTSTR)CA2WEX<>(pszOutputFileName), x, y, width, height);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Error[0x%08X]: CDXGICapture::CaptureToFile failed.\n", hr);
    }
}

/*
 * Class:     JNIScreenShotTest
 * Method:    getNumber
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JNIScreenShotTest_getNumber
(JNIEnv *env, jobject clz) {
    return 2;
}
```

My calls from java are as follows

```
File f = new File("Some file");
int x = some value;
int y = some value;
int width = some value;
int height = some value;

JNIScreenShot jniScreenShot = new JNIScreenShot();
jniScreenShot.(f.getAbsolutePath(), x,y,width,height)
```

This generates an error
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.tdkc.udop.screencapture.jniScreenShot.captureScreen(Ljava/lang/string;IIII)V

At first i thought something in my captureScreen was failing or maybe it was a difference in data types i was passing in.  So i created the getNumber method as a test

I get a similar error when calling getNumber()
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.tdkc.udop.screencapture.jniScreenShot.getNumber()I

Both of the error messages reference the Signature in the .h file so i know its finding the dll and attempting to call the right method.

Spent some time looking at the UnsatisfiedLinkError but most googled results show that when the library is loading which i've seen plenty of including when trying to use System.loadLibrary() instead of System.load()

It would appear that its finding the methods ok as the error contains the signature defined in my .h file for each method.

At this point i've tried following what seems like a million guides and tutorials on JNI and its been 2 days and i'm lost any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you run the program with `-Xlog:library*=trace` (need JDK 15+), what does it print? Is your library being loaded successfully? Does the symbol lookup for the native function search the right library?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your asking for.  My application is running from Eclipse.  Quick google of that line doesnt tell me what it does or where it saves a file ect can you elaborate?  is this a VM argument?

Comment: Yes, it's a VM argument. The output should be printed in the console. It's an option that enables extra logging about native library loading and symbol lookup. You could run `java -Xlog:help` in the console (cmd/powershell/sh/bash depending on the platform/shell you're using) or check the online documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/man/java.html#enable-logging-with-the-jvm-unified-logging-framework to get more information

Comment: With that VM argument i cant start my application i get an Java Virtual Machine Launcher followed by an Eclipse error dialog saying Cannont connect to VM.  That being said its loading the dll because the error message when it attempts the call matches the signature on the methods in my .h file

Comment: The output should tell you whether the right library is being loaded (it prints the path), and whether the symbol lookup is looking in the right library using the right name. FWIW, the only thing that matters for the lookup is the name of the function (there's no type information inside a DLL, at least not typically). You could use something like `dumpbin` (comes with Visual Studio) or [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) to verify that the DLL that is being loaded actually contains the symbol.

Comment: I stand corrected tried passing a int in my call to getNumber() and now i'm getting  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.tdkc.udop.screencapture.jniScreenShot.getNumber(I)I  So the error is not related to the signature in my .h file like i thought.  I'm running this as a 64 bit application and my dll is a 64 bit dll not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.tdkc.udop.screencapture.jniScreenShot.getNumber()I
```

It seems that your class is in a package. But, the name of your native function doesn't match this:

```
Java_JNIScreenShotTest_getNumber
```

The package name should be encoded in the name of the native function as well. From that error message, it looks like the name of your native function should be:

```
Java_com_tdkc_udop_screencapture_jniScreenShot_getNumber
```

---

Using `-Xlog:library*=trace` ([since JDK 15](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187305)) you could see the exact name the VM is using for the lookup. For instance:

```
[0.211s][info][library] Loaded library C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15\bin\nio.dll, handle 0x00007ffacf0f0000
...
[0.212s][info][library] Found Java_sun_nio_fs_WindowsNativeDispatcher_initIDs in library with handle 0x00007ffacf0f0000
```

Comment: To add to this: always recreate your headers and change your implementation to match, if you change a JNI package/class/method name

Comment: This is the problem as the .h file was built from a java file that didnt have the package on it.  Once I added the package information and had it regenerate the .h file it then changed my method names.  While this solves my problem it leaves me with another which is i'm assuming if the java file is ever moved it will break and not be able to find the correct method.  Is there a way to have the .h file method names not include the package information so that if the java file ever moves it doesnt affect it?

Comment: @Jeremy Not really, no. You might want to take a look at the [`registerNatives`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#registering-native-methods) API, which allows you to manually link native functions, but it requires calling out into native code first, and this first call would have the same package naming problem. IMO it's more trouble than it's worth. At least with the upcoming project Panama foreign function interface it will be easier to link against arbitrary native functions without having to have an exact name mapping.